# PowerBI REST API request GetGroupsAsAdmin returns AggregateException. An attempt to filter out personal workspaces

Tags: powershell, api, rest, powerbi, powerbi-api

I am retrieving data from Power BI Rest API following the instruction here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-get-groups-as-admin#grouptype

A call to retrieve all data works ok. Here is the URL that works:

```
$url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups?%24top="+$number_of_records+"&%24expand=dataflows,datasets,reports,dashboards,workbooks,users"
```

But this request return too much data that I want to filter it out.

In particular, I don't want to see personal workspaces.
But my calls return an AggregateException error.
Here are the URLs I tried that conform with the MSDocs but do not work:

Here I tried to filter out all "PersonalGroup" type

```
$url1 = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups?%24top=" + $number_of_records + '&%24filter=type ne' + " 'PersonalGroup'" + '&%24expand=dataflows,dashboards,reports,datasets,users'
```

And here I tried to keep everything except of "PersonalGroup" type

```
$url2 = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups?%24top=" + $number_of_records + '&%24filter=type eq' + " 'Group'" + ' or type eq' + " 'Personal'" + ' or type eq' + " 'Workspace'" + '&%24expand=dataflows,dashboards,reports,datasets,users'
```

Both throw the same error:

```
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod : One or more errors occurred.
At line:1 char:15
+     $Result = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url -Method GET
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...werBIRestMethod:InvokePowerBIRestMethod) [Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : One or more errors occurred.,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.InvokePowerBIRestMethod
```

Does anyone know how is this fixable as I can't find an answer online and I don't see any errors in my request

Comment: The exception says WriteError which is probably being caused by writing to a log file after the exception occurs.  A ssample of groups is shown here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters?force_isolation=true#standard-url-escape-characters

Comment: @jdweng, thank you for the recommendation.

I replaced all the special characters.

Here is how request look now `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups?%24top=5000&%24filter=type%20ne%20%27PersonalGroup%27&%24expand=dataflows,dashboards,reports,datasets,users`

Comment: It still doesn't work for 'ne', but works for 'eq'.

Comment: Maybe NE is just not returning anything and then you are getting an exception someplace else in the code.

Comment: The particular line with the `Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url -Method GET` gives me an error. I loaded the full data and there are values other than 'PersonalGroup' type.

Comment: You are returning $url1 or $usrl2 but then using $url (no number).  If the URL is null, the Invoke will fail.

Comment: I numerated "$url"s for simplicity of understanding. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Is the $url empty?  NE may be empty or the response may have a error and not return 200 OK.

Comment: No, the $url is the non-empty string value. Sorry if I am not fully understanding your question.

Comment: I did not say empty string value. It shold be an object

Comment: Yes, it's System.Object String

Comment: Is the string a valid URL?  The exception is due to string not being a url.  The exception is occurring here : $Result = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url -Method GET  Are you using the variable $url for two different purposes?